# Difference between "to pieces" and "into pieces"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

He tore it to pieces.
He tore it into pieces.

I am a bit confused..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the context of ripping up a piece of paper, for example, there is no difference in meaning.

However, 'torn to pieces' is used metaphorically in various ways. It can mean *emotionally distressed* (eg *I'm torn to pieces over the queen's death*). It can also mean that something has been ruined, spoiled or destroyed (eg *my dreams have been torn to pieces*). Saying something has been torn '*into* pieces' sounds much more literal, as it emphasises the various parts that are left over.

To 'tear *into* pieces' can also suggest that care is taken when making the tears. For example, you could tear a piece of bread into pieces in order to share it out equally. 'Tear to pieces' almost always suggests destruction.